# Cron job outputting php headers when piping to file

Tags: php, bash, cron, cpanel

I've got a bash script which runs 4 commands and redirects to a file. This script works fine when I run it myself from the CLI on my server. It does not work when I let cron run the script.

my file looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command > file.csv
command >> file.csv
command >> file.csv
command >> file.csv
```

I get the expected result when I run it myself but when cron runs it I get this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I execute the cron job like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/user/rest/of/path/script.sh >/dev/null
```

can someone please help? Driving me mad....

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php I am not able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was specifying a PATH property in the bash script.

I echoed the $PATH variable in my shell and copied this into the script and this seemed to solve things.